# Unable to login to AWS instance after installing cloud-init

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ami, cloud-init

I have a custom `ami` crated after importing an `.ova` file following the process outlined [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vm-import/latest/userguide/vmimport-image-import.html).

After spinning up an instance from that particular `ami`, I am able to login to the instance using `ubuntu@private-ip`.

I then proceed to installing `cloud-init`:

```
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt install -y cloud-init
```

(my `.ova` did not have the `cloud-init` when importing it)

I then reboot the instance (after `cloud-init`'s installation) and I keep getting the following:

```
ubuntu@private-ip's password: 
Permission denied, please try again.
ubuntu@private-ip's password:
```

Answer (score 0):

I replicated the process in a `VMware` player and it seems `cloud-init` is messing with the VM`s ssh configuration:

[image]